# Uncaught TypeError: React.createClass is not a function

Tags: reactjs

To make a react component, i used the following code

```
var React = require('react');

var RandomWords = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div >
        <h4>Random words come here</h4>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

module.exports =RandomWords;
```

and then i call this componnet in the root componnet using this:

```
define(["./RandomWords","react", "react-dom"],
  (React, ReactDOM) => {

      var Root = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
          return (
            <div >
              <h1>Welcome to our game</h1>
              <RandomWords/>
              <UserInput/>
              <Statistic/>
            </div>
          );
        }
      });



      ReactDOM.render(
        React.createElement(Root, null),
        document.getElementById('content')
      );
});
```

but it complains that:

```
Uncaught TypeError: React.createClass is not a function
```

It seems to me it is because of `define(["./RandomWords","react", "react-dom"]`, but i don't know how can i fix it?

Comment: `npm i react --save-dev` ?

Comment: Not getting any sort of error w/ that particular component; are you sure it's installed? https://jsfiddle.net/ofbosj5g/

Comment: yes react is installed and working correctly

Comment: No, but i have update my question, i think the problem is about how i call the **Randomwords**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this RequireJS? You specify three dependencies, but only use two. That will fail unless the one you don't use is the last one in the dependency array because the ones you pass to the function will mismatch. The order has to be consistent.

The way is is now, the `React` variable that is passed into the function is `RandomWords`, `ReactDOM` is `React` and `ReactDOM` is never injected.

Try

```
define(["./RandomWords","react", "react-dom"],
  (RandomWords, React, ReactDOM) => {
```